# docker data volume vs mounted host directory

Tags: docker

We can have a data volume in docker:

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/data/in/container --name test_container debian
$ docker inspect test_container
...
Mounts": [
    {
        "Name": "fac362...80535",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/fac362...80535/_data",
        "Destination": "/path/to/data/in/container",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true
    }
]
...
```

But if the data volume lives in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/fac362...80535/_data`, is it any different from having the data in a folder mounted using `-v /path/to/data/in/container:/home/user/a_good_place_to_have_data`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> is it any different from having the data in a folder mounted using -v /path/to/data/in/container:/home/user/a_good_place_to_have_data?

It is because, as mentioned in "[Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)"

> The host directory is, by its nature, host-dependent. For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from Dockerfile because built images should be portable. A host directory wouldn’t be available on all potential hosts.
>
> If you have some persistent data that you want to share between containers, or want to use from non-persistent containers, it’s best to create a named Data Volume Container, and then to mount the data from it.

You can combine both approaches:

```
 docker run --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

> Here we’ve launched a new container and mounted the volume from the `dbdata` container.
> We’ve then mounted a local host directory as `/backup`.
> Finally, we’ve passed a command that uses `tar` to backup the contents of the `dbdata` volume to a `backup.tar` file inside our `/backup` directory. When the command completes and the container stops we’ll be left with a backup of our `dbdata` volume.

Comment: Can you clarify what the Docker documentation means by that host directories are *host-dependent*? Are file permissions meant because they in some cases are a pain to replicate on another host when you move a container plus the mounted directory to another host?

Also what's the difference between named volumes and mounted directories? I understand that especially the sharing of persistent data between multiple containers is a use case for data volume containers. But in the case of persistent data only relevant to a single container I'm a bit lost :-).

Comment: @PermaFrost host-dependent means you cannot write a Dockerfile with a volume path from the host, since that Dockerfile could be build on any host, each with their own characteristics: a path valid on one host might not be available on another. That is why mounting an host folder is a *runtime* operation (docker run), not a compile time one (docker build)

Comment: @PermaFrost a named volume is host independent, and persistent. Even for one container only, that means I can export and restore a named volume on any host. See https://madcoda.com/2016/03/docker-named-volume-explained/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link, I will have a look at that article! :)

Comment: @VonC: Can you clarify what is the difference between creating a lvm on the host system and mounting on docker vs using the docker plugin to create lvm and mounting it? Should one be preferred over other?

Comment: @user1050619 a Logical volume Manager (LVM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) is specific to the Linux kernel and not to docker. So in the context of that question, I cannot clarify the difference, in that the answer is not directly related to LVM: it applies to docker volume, and you can have a lot of different volume drivers, some of them having nothing to do with LVM. Some are related: https://medium.com/@kalahari/docker-data-volume-snapshots-and-encryption-with-lvm-and-luks-ce80e0555225

Comment: Thanks @VonC, I found this one - http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/05/docker-lvm-plugin/ ..."Docker does not allow us to put a restriction on the size of the volume created. For use cases like OpenShift, where the Platform-as-a-service (PAAS) system wants to create a size-adjustable container, the docker volume command might not be good enough."

Comment: @user1050619 Interesting. Not sure if I can add it to the answer though.

Comment: how to do the same with `docker-compose.yml` is `--volume-from` supported in docker-compose

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung That is a good question on its own: please ask it separately.

Comment: May you please clarify how `/dbdata` is related to `dbdata` volume?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Re-reading my answet 7 years later, it seems I am talking about a dbdata container, from which we access the volume, presumably one in `/dbdata` inside that container.

Comment: @VonC: Would it be possible to describe how to create these volume? eg. If `dbdata` volume was created as '....' then we can backup data as `docker run --volumes_from ...'. It will really help to understand your examples.

Comment: @EugenKonkov Again, 7 years later, this is a bit fuzzy, but I suspect those volumes were created following one of the [options described in that answer in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173474/6309).

Answer (score 141):

Although using volumes and bind mounts feels the same (with the only change being the location of the directory), there are differences in behavior.

**Volumes vs Bind Mounts**

- With Bind Mount, a file or directory on the *host machine*  is mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its full or relative path on the host machine.
- With Volume, a new directory is created **within Docker's storage directory** on the host machine, and **Docker manages** that directory's content.

Volumes advantages over bind mounts:

- Volumes are easier to back up or migrate than bind mounts.
- You can manage volumes using Docker CLI commands or the Docker API.
- Volumes work on both Linux and Windows containers.
- Volumes can be more safely shared among multiple containers.
- Volume drivers allow you to store volumes on remote hosts or cloud providers, to encrypt the contents of volumes, or to add other functionality.
- A new volume’s contents can be pre-populated by a container.

**EDIT (9.9.2019):**
According to @Sebi2020 comment, Bind mounts are much easier to backup. Docker doesn't provide any command to backup volumes. You have to use temporary containers with a bind mount to create backups.

**[Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)**

> Created and managed by Docker. You can create a volume explicitly
> using the docker volume create command, or Docker can create a volume
> during container or service creation.
>
> When you create a volume, it is stored within a directory on the
> Docker host. When you mount the volume into a container, this
> directory is what is mounted into the container. This is **similar to
> the way that bind mounts work, except that volumes are managed by
> Docker and are isolated from the core functionality of the host
> machine.**
>
> A given volume can be mounted into multiple containers simultaneously.
> When no running container is using a volume, the volume is still
> available to Docker and is not removed automatically. You can remove
> unused volumes using docker volume prune.
>
> When you mount a volume, it may be named or anonymous. Anonymous
> volumes are not given an explicit name when they are first mounted
> into a container, so Docker gives them a random name that is
> guaranteed to be unique within a given Docker host. Besides the name,
> named and anonymous volumes behave in the same ways.
>
> Volumes also support the use of volume drivers, which allow you to
> store your data on remote hosts or cloud providers, among other
> possibilities.

[image: Volumes on the Docker host]

**[Bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)**

> Available since the early days of Docker. Bind mounts have limited
> functionality compared to volumes. When you use a bind mount, a file
> or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. The file
> or directory is referenced by its full path on the host machine. The
> file or directory does not need to exist on the Docker host already.
> It is created on demand if it does not yet exist. Bind mounts are very
> performant, but they rely on the host machine’s filesystem having a
> specific directory structure available. If you are developing new
> Docker applications, consider using named volumes instead. You can’t
> use Docker CLI commands to directly manage bind mounts.

[image: Bind mounts on the Docker host]

There is also `tmpfs mounts`.

**[tmpfs mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/)**

> A tmpfs mount is not persisted on disk, either on the Docker host or
> within a container. It can be used by a container during the lifetime
> of the container, to store non-persistent state or sensitive
> information. For instance, internally, swarm services use tmpfs mounts
> to mount secrets into a service’s containers.
> [image: tmpfs on the Docker host]

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/

Comment: Bind mounts are much easier to backup. Docker sadly does not provide any command to backup volumes. You have to use temporary containers with a bind mount to create backups

Comment: I was just about to ask how come volumes are easier to back up, but @Sebi2020 asked first. I think it's fair to edit the answer.

Comment: I second @Sebi2020. I came here when I was looking for ways to backup volumes and found them unnecessarily complicated to backup (unlike what I had intuitively thought). Bind mounts are much much easier to backup.

Comment: I came here also searching for the same. I do see as a major disadvantage of volume mounts that for an older version of docker, I had to remove the current version first when I wanted to upgrade it. This also removed all the docker data (images, containers, volumes). I'm not sure that will not ever happen again with an upgrade. And I agree that bind mounts are much easier to backup. You know precisely where the data is. It would be nice if the docker documentation would elaborate on the so-called advantages of volumes over bind mounts.

Comment: And as far as windows docker volumes concern: there is a lot that doesn't work on a windows docker host with respect to volumes. So that's not an advantage as well.

Comment: I feel this answer is very biased into volumes. It has no advantages of bind mounts, so let me give some. I guess everyone already said about bind mounts being easier to backup. On top of that volumes are using the network stack while bind mounts are using linux kernel. That makes volumes much slower, especially when you are doing an atomic operation eg. fseek, that is 800 times slower (benchmarked) on volume than on bind mount. Also volumes cannot take advantage of linux file cache, while bind mounts can (well, they technically can, but after the overhead of the network stack).

Answer (score 33):

Yes, this is quite different from a few perspectives.  Like you wrote in the question's title, it is about understanding why we need data volumes vs bind mount to host.

## Part 1 - Basic scenarios with examples

Lets take 2 scenarios.

**Case 1: Web server**
We want to provide our web server a configuration file that might change frequently. 
  For example:  exposing ports according to the current environment.
We can rebuild the image each time with the relevant setup or create 2 different images for each environment. Both of this solutions aren’t very efficient.

With *Bind mounts* Docker mounts the given source directory into a location inside the container. 
(The original directory / file in the read-only layer inside the union file system will simply be overridden).

For example - binding a dynamic port to nginx:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
     - type: bind #<-----Notice the type
       source: ./mysite.template
       target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
    ports:
     - "9090:8080"
    environment:
     - PORT=8080
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > 
        /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

(*) Notice that this example could also be solved using Volumes.

**Case 2 : Databases** 
Docker containers do not store persistent data -- any data that will be written to the writable layer in container’s union file system will be lost once the container stops running.

But what if we have a database running on a container, and the container stops -  that means that all the data will be lost?

*Volumes* to the rescue. 
Those are named file system trees which are managed for us by Docker.

For example - persisting Postgres SQL data:

```
services:    
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    volumes:
     - type: volume #<-----Notice the type
       source: dbdata
       target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Notice that in this case, for named volumes, the source is the name of the volume
(for anonymous volumes, this field is omitted).

## Part 2 - Comparison

**Differences in management and isolation on the host**

*Bind mounts*  exist on the host file system and being managed by the host maintainer. 
 Applications / processes outside of Docker can also modify it.

*Volumes* can also be implemented on the host, but Docker will manage them for us and they can not be accessed outside of Docker.

**Volumes are a much wider solution**

Although both solutions help us to separate the data lifecycle from containers,
by using *Volumes* you gain much more power and flexibility over your system.

With *Volumes* we can design our data effectively and decouple it from other parts of the system by storing it in dedicated remote locations (e.g., in the cloud) and integrate it with external services like backups, monitoring, encryption and hardware management.

Comment: I thank you for giving usage examples, especially with docker-compose ymls

Comment: Are these same? `    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    volumes:
     - type: volume #<-----Notice the type
       source: dbdata  
       target: /var/lib/postgresql/data` From your 1.2 example.

Answer (score 9):

The difference between host directory and a data volume is in that that Docker manages the latter by placing it into the `$DOCKER-DATA-DIR/volumes` directory and attaching a reference to it (names or randomly generated ids). That is you get a little bit of convenience.

Both host directories and data volumes are directories on the host. Both are host dependent. You can't reference either of them in a `Dockerfile`; the `VOLUME` directive creates a new nameless (with randomly generated id) volume every time you launch a new container and cannot reference an existing volume.

*** `$DOCKER-DATA-DIR` is `/var/lib/docker` here unless you changed the defaults.

Comment: In my case it looks like: `overlay          38G   19G   18G  51% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b94...c973/merged`