# postgresql persist data: which is better named volume or bind mount

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

Option 1: (named container. the volume is identified by its name. It store its data in the /var/lib/docker/volumes/nameofthevolume)

```
# create the volume in advance
  $ docker volume create test_vol
```

Option: 2 (here name of the volume `bind-test` does not matter, what matter is which local path `/home/user/test` it mounts to, which is persistant. Rather than `/var/lib/docker/volume/somevolumename` `/home/user/somedatafolder` makes more readability. Cons: we have to ensure that the `/home/user/somedatafolder` exists.)

```
 # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    bind-test:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /home/user/test

 or:

version: '3'
services:
myservice:
    volumes:
      - ./path:/volume/path
```

The downside of bind mounts is that it places files that are managed by containers, with the uid/gid from the container, inside a path likely used by other users on the host, often with a different uid/gid on the host. The result is permission issues either on the host or inside the container. You need to align uid/gid's between the two to avoid this.

Comment: Perhaps see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173474/6489829

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker data volume vs mounted host directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357252/docker-data-volume-vs-mounted-host-directory)

Comment: how do we copy volume to another host

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, there isn't a big difference between bind mount and Docker named volumes.

I tend to prefer keeping persistent data from Docker services in Docker volumes. You can then use tools like `docker system df -v` to inspect what your application uses.

As for exporting the data, you can use `docker cp`

```
docker cp someContainer:/somedir/ .
```